# Rails paperclip trying to add a photo to a model with a relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm have a model Product that I want to be able to add multiple photos to. So I got the paperclip gem, and since I want *multiple* photos, I made another table called Photos with a one-to-many relationship with my Product model. This way I can assign make multiple records in the photos table each with a paperclip attachment and each one reference a Product.

But I can't seem to get my upload image functionality to work, nothing even gets saved to the database. Every other field will get updated when I edit it, but nothing gets saved into the photos table. What am I missing? Relevant code below:

Models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos

end
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

Product Controller

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
    @product = Product.new
  end

def update

    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      end
        else
          respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            #format.html { render action : "edit" }
          end
        end
end
```

View

```
<% for product in @products %>

<%= simple_form_for product, :html => { :method => 'put', :multipart => true} do |f| %>
    <%= token_tag form_authenticity_token %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <%= product.photos.each do |photo| %>
            <%= image_tag photo.image.url %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <%= f.input :name, :input_html => {:value => product.name} %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <%= f.association :category, :selected => product.category.id %>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <%= f.input :price, :input_html => {:value => product.price}%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <%= f.input :short_description, :input_html => {:value => product.short_description} %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <%= fields_for :photos do |f_i| %>
            <%= f_i.file_field :image %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="large-6 columns">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
    </div>


<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you have accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos in your product model?

Comment: So I tried adding that and re-saving the photo but it still didn't work. There is no error given but when I go into my DB and look at the Photos table there are no rows saved.

Comment: Could you please specify the a rails and paperclip version. Also share the generated server log upon submission of form with images.

Answer (score 0):

You just needs to add this line in Product model.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
```

That will work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had several things wrong (all now corrected and it's working properly. IIRC these were the main issues I was having:

1. missing accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos (as pointed out above)
2. not using simple_fields_for (since I was using the simple forms gem)
3. Missing validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type =>
   ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"] in my Photos model
   (necessary when submission is successful, this can also be disabled
   as another option
4. I need to build my associated objects in the products controller
   like this: @products.each do |item|  item.photos.build
5. Had to change product_params to this: (don't think i gave the
   original code here, also I'm going to tighten up that permit later)
   params.require(:product).permit!

Think that was the main stuff. Thanks for the help.